# How to deal with bimodal feature in Logistic Regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, distributions, logistic, data-transformation

I am working on a binary classification problem where one of the most interesting features has a distribution which looks more or less bimodal. Here is the distribution plot of that feature:
[image]

The two modes seem to correspond to two classes. When I look at the distribution of this feature corresponding to each class separately, this is what I get:
[image]

[image]

Clearly, one of them is more like a log-normal distribution, and the other is more like normal, and the two peaks in the original distribution seems to correspond to two different classes. My question is how do I deal with this kind of bimodality in Logistic regression. Also, would other machine learning algorithms be more suitable for this kind of a problem?

Comment: What does it mean to “deal with” the feature? Bimodality of the distribution isn’t an obstacle for logistic regression.

Comment: The features in a logistic regression do not have distribution assumptions (except that constant features are unhelpful), so what problem do you see with your bimodal feature?

Comment: If you know the two classes then you can incorporate them into your logistic regression

Comment: @Henry I take that comment to mean that the two classes are the classes being predicted.

Comment: @Dave you may be correct.  I had guessed these were credit scores, that the two classes were something like "does not have a formal job" and "has a formal job" and the prediction was "will default" or "will not default"

Comment: @Henry These are credit scores, which is the feature of a classification problem like "will default" or "will not default".

Comment: Nothing there looks lognormal to me. There is some fine structure in the distributions, which is probably secondary.

Comment: What would you do with dummy variables? The variables with zero and ones values. You use them in logistic regression.

Comment: @Aksakal I think I get that your point is not to worry about features lacking normal distributions, but I’m not sure that’s clear to someone who doesn’t already know not to be concerned about a lack of feature normality.

Comment: It puzzles me why people think features should be normally distributed. It is not implied anywhere in regression

Answer (score 4):

Stick that feature in your regression like you would any other feature. Logistic regression makes no assumption that the features have a particular distribution. I suspect this misconception [comes from the same confusion that people have about OLS linear regression.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/563175/247274)

Since the distribution of that feature for each $y$ category is not just a shift in location, you might benefit from using some nonlinear functions of this feature, such as a spline, but the distributions are so different that I expect this feature to give considerable discriminative ability on its own.